# How to Integrate botframework in Mobile app...?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, botframework, chatbot

I made a chatbot using the MS bot framework in Nodejs. For the purpose of rendering the chatbot in HTML without iframes I used  React Component as shown in this link https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat. Now I want to integrate this into a mobile app. How do i do this? Can you point me the right direction. My only restriction is that I have to not use iframes in anyways in integration either in web or in the mobile app.Does the use of React component will affect the integration in any way?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Actually Reactjs is a frontend framework, if you want to use React to build android applications, you can try to leverage [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/), where I think you can implement the Bot React Component.

Otherwise, you can try to WebView in android to embed your bot application's endpoint. Which I think is the simplest method. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-design-pattern-embed-app for the similar scenario.

Comment: So if it create my app using react native which has only one function i.e to provide the interface to chat with the bot. Is it possible to integrate this app with an existing android app.?
if yes how?

Comment: You insist on using  React Component, which is a javascript component, should not be used in Android. For inplement bot framework in android, there is another function, which is to implement `Direct Line` in Android. You can refer to the unofficial repo https://github.com/brijrajsingh/DirectLineAndroidSample for hint.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html
I found this. 
It shows that I can create a app in react native and then integrate in an existing android app.
What's your opinion on this.

Comment: It looks like customize create a bridge in android and javascript script. I am not farmilar with andoird, but this look cool. You can try it.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion.
I will try it.

In your answer you said  "Otherwise, you can try to WebView in android to embed your bot application's endpoint. Which I think is the simplest method. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-design-pattern-embed-app for the similar scenario"

Can you please elaborate how this method will work.?

Comment: I am not familiar with android, but I think you can try https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html in your android application, use the embed bot's endpoint as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the help !!